# How can I add view from my NopCommerce Plugin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I am doing customization in NopCommerce. I have to create a custom view of Category Page. And I am managing that from my Plugin. I had override the Category Action method from my plugin, but need to call view file.

How can I call view ? I don't want to use Embedded Resources type view. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. You cannot do it the way you want to.

The easiest solution is to create a new theme (or use existing). Then copy the view you want to change to this theme and it will use this instead of the core one.

*general recommendation below, not part of solution below*

---

If you do it this way you will have to merge manually the rest of the way with the official nop-solution. If your changes are not extreme, I would recommend changing the existing view and methods (you are editing the core), and keep merging with official solution. Or you will create problems for yourself.

I would instead take advantage of Mercury Synchronize option where you can have your own rep and offical nop synchronized.

Also why are you not taking advantage of the category template system in NOP? Since you said that you were managing a category view?

I basically think you are going down the wrong path to begin with...